# Optimizing re-render in react context confuses me. It actually prevents its context subscriber from re-rendering?

Tags: reactjs, document

According to [React doc](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext#optimizing-re-renders-when-passing-objects-and-functions), useMemo and useCallback help performant optimization because comparison between rendering works correctly.

In my understanding, however, whenever parent component re-renders, its child components also re-render. Since react context works with the provider, all context subscribers are under parent provider. So parent provider re-rendering probably causes child re-rendering as well.

The statement below of React doc confuses me. Anyone can explain this?

> even if MyApp needs to re-render, the components calling useContext(AuthContext) won’t need to re-render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my understanding, however, whenever parent component re-renders, its child components also re-render.

That's true by default, but [React.memo](https://react.dev/reference/react/memo) can be used to skip rerendering of a child if its props have not changed. So if you're using React.memo to improve performance, you need to make sure your context value isn't changing all the time, which would eliminate the gains from React.memo

For example, the documentation you linked has `MyApp` returning the following:

```
const MyApp = () => {
  // ...
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      <Page />
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Suppose that `Page` is implemented something like this:

```
import { memo } from 'react';

const Page = memo(() => {
  return (
    <ChildThatUsesContext />
  )
})

const ChildThatUsesContext = () => {
  const value = useContext(AuthContext);

  // ... do stuff
}
```

If `MyApp` rerenders and the `contextValue` does not change, then both `Page` and `ChildThatUsesContext` can skip rendering.

If `MyApp` rerenders and the `contextValue` *does* change, then `Page` will be able to skip rendering, but `ChildThatUsesContext` (and all its descendants) will have to render because it called `useContext(AuthContext);`

So the reason to memoize `contextValue` is to put us in that first case more often, with *all* of the components skipping rendering, not just `Page`.

Comment: Oh, I see. There is React.memo behind the scene.